# Sitecore config include file relative paths and transformation

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, config-transformation

I am trying to do do a URL redirect from a site to other
when user requests the following url, using URL redirect I redirect the request to a different port on the same server.

**www.mydomain.com/sitecoresite** => **www.mydomain.com:81/sitecoresite**

Now the problem is `sitecoresite` under `81` port has a `datafolder` path which is acting a relative to first site. how can I make to work with `sitecoresite` path.

How can I make this path relative?

```
 <sc.include file="/_EnvironmentSettings/datafolder.config" />
```

Second question is how can I use web.config transformations on sitecore section of sitecore sites.

Comment: What you mean the `dataFolder` is relative to the first site? Both sites are pointing to the same dataFolder? With regards to config transforms, don't do that for `Sitecore` section and instead use [patch include files](https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/05/all-about-web-config-include-files-with-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree with jammykam on using patch files for updating Sitecore settings, there are occasions where you might want to transform the patch files for a release build vs a debug build. For example, SMTP settings etc...

For that I use the SlowCheatah plugin for VS - it creates the transforms nicely and then my deployment server does the transforms on deploy. Although I would recommend that you *don't* create lots of transforms per environment. A simple release transform with variables set via your deployment server would be better.

Comment: would you be able use slowcheeta transformation on sitecore configs like  <sc.include file="/_EnvironmentSettings/datafolder.config" /> ??? usingg xdt:transfor and xdt:replce=____?

Comment: @HaBo yes, you can do all the same things on configs in the include folder or the standard sitecore config as you can with the web.config (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx)